# Facebook photo upload c++

Tags: facebook-oauth

i am using the following url for posting message to user wall via my application

```
https://graph.facebook.com/100002944254185/feed?client_id=129042607197622&message=found&oauth_version=2.0&oauth_nonce=5887e5b11904194f7d217e9b7f795d62&oauth_timestamp=1317623602&oauth_consumer_key=129042607197622&oauth_token=CCCB1XRLDTbYBAOwHYTO6qw1NswhUt99e0ov9yYG4CYAXahGi1VkycZAo8rWWDWfuq21w2jjZA49f4zNLZAM3JMGfTlj8d4rPTnTcvVcDk7T9iWY5HuY&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_signature=96b104ee6b4576e7526390b287e7a32d&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/mymegha/
```

and this is working

what will be the format for uploading a photo?

What all should be included in the url and what else in the header. How the format will be?

Please help me out...

Comment: Why don't you just look at the Facebook SDK documentation?  This has little to do with oauth to be honest.

Comment: i need to do the application without using available SDK. So need to specify oauth headers from the application itself. Can you help me out with required format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved. Inorder to upload photo the data should be specified as  "multipart/form-data". It works..